# How to find out the html textbox's control in .cs file of C#.net

Tags: asp.net

//aspx file

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server"/><br/>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

// cs file

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //There are so many control.I am accessing value in string
  string s1 = "Text1";
  TextBox AgeTextBox = Page.FindControl(s1) as TextBox;

  AgeTextBox.Text;           
 }
```

Comment: please include more than just code, like a explanation of what you are trying to do, whats not working about your code, any errors you may be getting etc

Comment: What we are doing with server side control in asp.net (Use of findcontrol ())same want to in html control.

Comment: Please ask the question in proper English, so that we can help you better. ***Are you asking how to find an input control's ID based on the text value?*** If so, you might end up with multiple input controls, because some might have same value.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using a literal HTML input, represented by an `HtmlInputText` in **ASP.NET**:

**1)** Add runat attribute to say that this control will run at server, then you can access it directly from the code behind:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server"/><br/>
```

**2)** Access it from name:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  /*Dos stuff*/
  string text = Text1.Value;
}
```

For more information about [HTML Input Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the value of html textbox by using name attribute. (if you dont want to make it a server control)

```
 <input id="Text1" type="text" name="txtname"/><br/>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

// cs file

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string ttext = Request["txtname"];

        }
```

Comment: I don't want value of control.I want find out id of control.So I check control's visibility.There are so many dynamically created control.That's why value is taken in string...

Comment: ahh ok, but you didn't mention this in your question.

Comment: I forgot to mention.Do u know how to do it?

Comment: dont know how to get it in c#, but if you tell me your goal behind it. may i can suggest some other way of doing it.